# clarification of ALTER DATABASE error message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I took a SQL Server 2008 database offline:

```
alter database FOO set offline;
```

Then I copied its MDF and LDF physical files to a new folder on another hard drive.

Then I ALTERed the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE FOO 
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = FOO_data, FILENAME = 'H:\SQL2008DATA\FOO.mdf' );

ALTER DATABASE FOO 
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = FOO_log, FILENAME = 'H:\SQL2008DATA\FOO.ldf' );
```

which results in these status error messages, where xxx = `data` or `log`:

> The file "UZ_{xxx}" has been modified in the system catalog. The new path will be used the next time the database is started.

I bring the database back online:

```
ALTER DATABASE FOO SET ONLINE;
```

and then I try to delete the old data and log files, but am getting an error that the log file cannot be deleted because it is open in SQL Server.

Do I have to shut down and restart the entire database (i.e. bounce the SQL Server process) before the LDF file will be released?

Comment: I would certainly be extremely 150% certain that you've updated the system catalog correctly.  If Windows thinks the file is open, it *is* open, which likely indicates SQL Server is actually using that file.  Ensure you have a valid backup of the database in question before moving forward.

Comment: But I made 200% certain.  SQL Server reports that the ALTER command has succeeded with the log file.  I have done the process a couple of times. Also, this query reports the new location: `SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName, name AS LogicalFileName, physical_name AS PhysicalFileName 
FROM sys.master_files AS mf`

Comment: But what about the question: do I have to bring the database back online only, or does the entire SQL Server process have to be bounced. The success error message is ambiguous.  What is "database" and what is "started"?

Comment: I was just going to suggest looking at that.  And you *do* have a good backup?

Comment: Well, I have backups. You only know if they're "good" when you try to use them.

Comment: Also, this is a "dry run" on a dev machine. I'm planning to do this again on a production one.

Comment: ahhhh.... that makes a difference.!  You can use SysInternals Process Monitor to find out who has a file open - it will likely tell you SQL Server does have the file open.  I would also see if SQL Server has the file open in the new location.  If it *does* I would *guess* that means SQL Server didn't properly close the file *handle* when setting the database offline.  I'm surprised you could copy the file if SQL Server didn't release the handle when taking the database offline.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/232830